# Hosting multiple visual studio projects from single solution on single port

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am trying to host two projects from single solution in visual studio on the same port.
How it could be achieved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have two projects in my visual studio solution file.First project is running on localhost:4200/ . I want to run the second project on same localhost port.  Is it possible to run both the projects on same port(4200)?